# Modify constructor arguments before passing it to superclass constructor in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

I have a superclass:

```
class Filter(val param: ComplexFilterParams){
    def this(config: String) = this(parseStrConfig(config))
```

And I need to create a subclass that gets a String argument and then parses it **in another way** and creates ComplexFilterParams.

Something like that:

```
class NewFilter(str:String) extends Filter {
```

Is there a way to do it?

I got one solution. But I think it's ugly. I create companion object, define there a convert method and do next:

```
class NewFilter(str:String) extends Filter(NewFilter.convert(str)) {
```

Comment: The code at the end looks OK, but not so sure about using `def this` rather than an `apply` method in the companion object.

Answer (score 2):

You can go mush easier with another `apply` implementation in companion object like:

```
class NewFilter(val param: ComplexFilterParams) extends Filter(param){
//other implementations
}


object NewFilter {
  def apply(str: String) = new NewFilter(convert(str))

  def convert(str: String): ComplexFilterParams = ...
}

val filter = NewFilter("config string")
```